# How to effectively destroy tanks?

Tags: battlefield-4

In Battlefield 4 there are wide variety of rocket launchers (guided, unguided, etc.).

- What launchers are most effective, in terms of available ammo and dealt damage?
- What is best weapon to have against tanks, without friendly support with additional ammo?

Comment: May I suggest a tank?

Comment: Probably the Javelin, but you must maintain a lock or have a friendly Recon who can paint it for you. Although I think most Recon's will be trying to C4 it, rather than paint it for you.

Comment: You can kill a tank as engineer in under 2 seconds, without mines, but stationary AT. Select your RPG(only RPG works here), enter AT, shot in the back, leave AT, shot RPG, tank down, "f**king hacker" chat incoming.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To take down a tank all by yourself, the best way is C4. It takes 3 C4 to be sure to kill a LAV, tank or boat. Jeeps and Armored transport (Humvees, Vans, etc) takes 2 for a sure kill.

Note that 2 piece of **C4** might kill a tank if you put them on the right spot (mostly on it's rear from what I found). If you put two pieces on the sides, it will disable the vehicle and leave it burning giving time to the driver to jump out. If you put the 2 pieces of C4 on the front, it will disable but not put the vehicle on fire.

1 piece of C4 does a mobility hit for sure which can allow you to put more C4 instead of the tank running off.

Mines are also a good way to take care of tanks, but you must place them near it and hope it runs over it (or shoot them with the Rex/magnum/slugs from shotguns) or place them in popular spots for vehicles to get that random kill 5 minutes later.

**For the launchers, this is what I found:**
[image]

**Also, I found this forum post:** 
http://bf4central.com/battlefield-4-rocket-launchers/

For the damage stats versus vehicles per launchers, I could not find the stats. But I've heard that RPGs do the same damage as a tank shell. The angle is (like in BF3) primordial in BF4. If your rocket hits at 50 degrees, it will do around 20 to 25 damage while hitting a tank square on will do a disable in most cases. Tanks are also more resilient on the front to damage. Sides have less armor and even less armor to the rear.

Overall, killing a tank alone is easier with **C4** since a good tank driver will rarely get killed by one engineer. However, to maximise your rockets potential, doing a 90 degree hit on the rear of the tank is the most effective way to kill it and the **RPG** is the one doing the most damage according to what I read.

Also, repair tools work wonders if you can sneak up on the tank, but that usually ends up in a suicide when the tank blows up (in BF3 you could survive with less than 10 HP, but in BF4 even if I stay at maximum Repair tool range, I still die).

Sources not linked before:

http://forum.symthic.com/battlefield-4-technical-discussion/5689-bf4-engineer-launcher-stats/

EDIT: Added mines,also, a guy took the time for 3 of the launchers:
http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_4/comments/1q39oy/rocket_damage_to_vehicles/

EDIT: RPG vs SMAW analysis

Comment: Well I was gonna answer this but I got stuck on the phone! Great answer, +1.  I am not sure if OP was looking for best weapon / vehicle unlock for all positions (was thinking about answering that instead to help).

Comment: I thought it was how to kill vehicles with infantry since he talked about launchers. Also, since most people haven't gotten all the unlocks yet, the vehicle composition that is the best has yet to be found I think.

If he wants that, Ill edit my answer with more info.

Comment: Dont forget mines. The weakest part of the tank is its underside. Get it to go over a mine or 2 and boom!

Comment: In-game description states that SMAW rockets fly faster than RPG, but do less damage. Is it so? I have not unlocked all launchers yet, so I cannot test them in-game or on test range.

Comment: I noticed the MBT LAW Locks on in flight, but the locking on does seem very sporadic. I managed to take a chopper down with one yesterday but I have no idea if it was a lucky shot or it did lock on.

Comment: Any data on the damages when the target is laserpainted?

Comment: MBT LAW rockets locked in flight when near ground or air target, i never hit jet with it, but i often see as it guides itself at choppers.

Comment: nothing on laser painted. A guy did test on the ground vehicles and the SMAW indeed does less damage than the RPG, see the edit.

Comment: From my personal experience in 700hours, destroying a tank as a single engineer is easy in one scenario, and only in one.
If you have good cover (like a rock or something), aren't noticed yet, shot one RPG 90° in the rear side. The driver either will jump out, or turning the turrent towards you. By the time the turrent turns, get in cover, wait for the tanks first shot, shot your second RPG, GG. This is a free kill in 4 out of 5 cases. Any other scenario (1:1) is much harder, strongly depends on enemies skill and luck.

Answer (score 1):

By my playing experience there is 2 infantry weapons, that can kill tank with 2 shots:

1. RPG in rear at 90 angle (deals ~52 dmg) - instant kill
2. Javelin on laser painted target (deals 45 dmg) - causes fire, if not repaired, vehicle will explode.

Any other uses and launchers need more hits to kill.

Comment: TOW and TV-Missle in the back are 2hit too.

Comment: TV missile causes ~42 damage and ignores active protection, not sure about rear damage coefficient. My question was more about infantry carried launchers.

Answer (score 0):

the RPG is definitely the most effective for tank damage but is the slowest and suffers most from the projectile dropping at greater distances .