# Which guided Engineer anti-tank or ant-vehicle launcher does the most damage?

Tags: battlefield-4

I assume that the 2 dumb fire anti-vehicle launchers do the most damage, but I'm not sure which of the locking or guided anti-tank missiles can deal the most damage.

[image: Rpg]

The dumb fire missiles can be great for close engagements, but they can be a little useless for hitting non-stationary armor at range.

If I want to hit a long range target, I want to do as much damage as possible with each hit, regardless of the technical difficulty of landing a hit.  So that gets me wondering which one of the launchers does the most the damage.  Some of the descriptions of the launchers give vague clues to their damage but no definitive info.

[image]

Which of the locking or guided anti-tank launchers does the most damage per hit?

(Also as a bonus: do you have a link that lists the damage outputs of the various launchers?)

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139001/how-to-effectively-destroy-tanks

Comment: @IvanSolntsev - Hey Ivan, I think its not a duplicate, since I'm asking about damage and a specific weapon.  Your question isn't directed at damage details, and is for tanks in general.  I think the questions overlap after reading the details, but mine is a more specific case than yours.  And would get a more direct answer.

Comment: The selected answer for yours says "For the damage stats versus vehicles per launchers, I could not find the stats. "  which would indicate that my question was not answered by yours.

Comment: The related question has all the discussion you need to answer your own question, including the numbers.
http://forum.symthic.com/battlefield-4-technical-discussion/5689-bf4-engineer-launcher-stats/

Comment: @DavidYell - sorry but you are flat out incorrect.  The link you provided, like the answer, says "Launcher stats (except impact damage) values ".  I want the max impact value and weapon name, which are not provided.

Comment: Well actually to defend their reasoning it does answer your "bonus" question....

Comment: Well to fair again, those stats don't include the impact damage.  So in a sense, you could say it does not answer the bonus question.  I believe that's the most important damage stat, and because its missing, the table is not as helpful for answering this question as it appears.

Comment: When you play in multiplayer match, each hit immediately give you points. This points is 1 for every % of vehicle health. So you can measure values for yourself. MBT LAV gives 21 and Javelin 30. For other rockets damage is related to angle of hit. At this moment if you count minimal guaranteed damage - than it is Javelin (for distances less than 350m).

Comment: Then you need to revise your question to make it more concise, as it seems I'm not alone in my understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: @DavidYell - I disagree, but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @IvanSolntsev - good point, hopefully someone will put that in answer format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you play in multiplayer match, each hit immediately give you points. This points is 1 for every % of vehicle health. So you can measure values for yourself.

From my experience:

MBT LAV

[image: MBT LAV]

- fly by straight line, no vertical drop, guides itself near vehicles and placed equipment. Against tanks it gives 21% damage, 30% on laser designated target.

FGM-148 Javelin

[image: FGM-148 Javelin]

- lock on weapon, requires lock til target is hit. Against tank it gives 30% damage (45% against laser designated target). Maximum distance: 300 m regular lock, 500 m laser designated target.

FGM-172 SRAW

[image: FGM-172 SRAW]

- guided missile, no vertical drop, follows crosshairs in ADS. Regular hit damage is affected by side and angle of hit. I didn't used it lately, so can't tell accurate numbers. For laser designated targets, deals 33% damage, lock distance: 300 m.

If you have SRAW unlocked, it is your best bet. When I fly in attack helicopter, most of my deaths from SRAW. If there is sniper in you team, who laser-designates targets, then switch to Javelin.

Images extracted from battlelog.battlefield.com